# phonegap project not working on ripple emulator in osx

Tags: ios, macos, cordova, emulation, ripple

i am trying to run phonegap ios project on ripple emulator on osx but it seems to be not working got this error:

> Cannot GET /platforms/ios/www/index.html
>   using this url :
>       http://localhost:4400/platforms/ios/www/index.html?enableripple=cordova-3.0.0

and this is my terminal console:

```
Users-MacBook:ossservices User$ ripple emulate --path platforms/ios/www
INFO: Server instance running on: http://localhost:4400
INFO: CORS XHR proxy service on: http://localhost:4400/ripple/xhr_proxy
INFO: JSONP XHR proxy service on:http://localhost:4400/ripple/jsonp_xhr_proxy
INFO: Could not find cordova as a local module. Expecting to find it installed globally.
INFO: Using Browser User Agent (String)
INFO: Set Device User Agent (String): "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.1; Galaxy Nexus Build/ITL41F) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19"
```